# How do I resolve "cannot find module for path X" importing a local Go module?

Tags: go, vgo

In my Go project, I want to break out some generic functionality into a Go module, separate from the main project. I'm doing this outside of GOPATH in keeping with go's future. I don't want to publish the module on GitHub or anywhere else.

All my attempts to import this module into the main project result in:

```
cannot find module for path X
```

I've run `go mod init X` in the module's folder. The contents of its `go.mod` file is:

```
module X
```

Building or installing this module seems to do nothing. I've found no sign of it in `$GOPATH/pgk/mod`.

I've tried a variety of import statements:

- `import "X"`
- `import "../x"`  ([relative path to the module directory](https://tip.golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Relative_import_paths))
- `import "../x/X"` (path to the directory + module name)

Help!

Comment: This relates to the more general question of [How to use a module that is outside of “GOPATH” in another module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328952/how-to-use-a-module-that-is-outside-of-gopath-in-another-module).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

So you wrote a Go "library" module `X` which:

- you don't want to publish on GitHub or elsewhere
- you want to import and use in your project (the "main" module).

### Use a `replace` directive along with `require`

In your main module's `go.mod`, add the following lines:

```
require "X" v0.0.0
replace "X" v0.0.0 => "{local path to the X module}"
```

The path should point to the root directory of `X`. It can be absolute or relative.

To import package *util* from module *X*:

```
import "X/util"
```

(You don't import modules. You import packages from modules.)

---

### Explanation

[Go's module functionality](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) is designed for publicly published modules. Normally, a module's name is both its unique identifier and the path to its public repo. When your [go.mod](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#gomod) declares a module dependency with the `require` directive, Go will automatically find and retrieve the specified version of the module at that path.

If, for example, your `go.mod` file contains `require github.com/some/dependency v1.2.3`, Go will retrieve the module from GitHub at that path. But if it contains `require X v0.0.0`, "X" isn't an actual path and you will get the error `cannot find module for path X`.

The `replace` directive allows you to specify a replacement path for a given module identifier and version. There are [many reasons you'd want to do this](https://go.dev/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive), such as to test changes to a module before pushing them to the public repo. But you can also use it to bind a module identifier to local code you don't ever intend to publish.

More details in the Go Modules documentation:

- [Can I work entirely outside of VCS on my local filesystem?](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-i-work-entirely-outside-of-vcs-on-my-local-filesystem)
- [When should I use the replace directive?](https://go.dev/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Jeez, wish this was number 1 on google. Had to read a lot of stuff before I finally got to this proper explanation.

Comment: It took me long time before I come to this answer. Big Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to use Go modules, you don't need to. As of Go v1.13, by default, go modules are used. Therefore, you need to tell explicitly if you don't want to do this.

Example:

main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "./pakk"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello" + pakk.World())
}
```

pakk/pakk.go:

```
package pakk

func World() string {
    return " world"
}
```

In this case, running `go run main.go` will output

```
build command-line-arguments: cannot find module for path .../pakk
```

but running

```
GO111MODULE=off go run main.go
```

will output

```
Hello world
```

Comment: I tested this `GO111MODULE=off` option and it worked.

Comment: Is there a way to do this if I want to have my local package pakk but also have other outside modules? Right now if I turn GO111MODULE=off it looks like outside packages such as "github.com/go-chi/chi" cannot be found

Answer (score 3):

Spent 4 days figuring this out. Very disapointed, but the way to import ./X

is as following:

first issue this magic command:

```
go mod init poop/strawberry/monkey
```

then you can EASILLY import your ./X folder:

```
import  (
"poop/strawberry/monkey/X"
)
```

Folder structure:

```
./X/X.go
./main.go
./go.mod
```

contents of go.mod:

```
module poop/strawberry/monkey
```

this is the awesome solution from go module creators

```
https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-init

module path: A path that identifies a module and acts as a prefix for package import paths within the module. For example, "golang.org/x/net"
```

Comment: this is much better than other solutions

Answer (score 0):

**go mod init** api.com

// "api.com" name your app  , it's alike swift 's bundle identifier , your can also "whatever.youlike"

[myExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhxcK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**Error ?**  Go cannot resolve the path to your modules, this is probably from misconfiguration or (not configuring) of the "go.mod" file used for project dependency tracking.

**Solution**  lets assume your project folder looks like below;

/
|-- folderOne/
|-- folderTwo/
|-- folderThree/
|-- main.go

```
 And the main.go script imports the modules  folderOne,folderTwo and folderFour's script (folderfour.go) imports the module folderThree.
    
    folderOne:
    execute in the commandline:
go mod init github.com/../folderOne (i.e path from github.com folder to folderOnes)
    The go mod init command creates a go.mod file to track your code's dependencies
    
    folderTwo:
    execute in the commandline:
go mod init github.com/../folderTwo (i.e path from github.com folder to folderTwos)
    The go mod init command creates a go.mod file to track your code's dependencies
    
    folderThree:
    execute in the commandline:
go mod init github.com/../folderThree (i.e path from github.com folder to folderThrees)
    The go mod init command creates a go.mod file to track your code's dependencies
    
    folderFour:
    execute in the commandline: 
go mod init github.com/../folderThree (i.e path from github.com folder to folderFour)
    Go to the folderFours script and import the module folderThree i.e 
    import "github.com/../folderThree"
    
    in folderfours commandline: 
$ go mod edit -replace github.com/{pathto}/folderThree=./folderThree**
    
    then execute: go mod tidy
    
    in your projects root folder execute the command: go mod init github.com/../ProjectRootDirectory (i.e path from github.com folder to ProjectRootDirectory)
    
    then to import the modules, i.e folderThree, folderTwo, folderOne
    execute the following at the projects root folder(ie folder with main.go)
$ go mod edit -replace github.com/{pathto}/folderOne=./folderOne
$ go mod edit -replace github.com/{pathto}/folderTwo=./folderTwo
$ go mod edit -replace github.com/{pathto}/folderFour=./folderFour
    
then execute;
$ go mod tidy
and then
$ go run main.go
```