# Go module init without VCS/Git fails with cannot determine module path

Tags: go

I'm trying to initialize a new go project with go module (using go 1.11). I don't plan to publish it in github or elsewhere, it is just a temporary/test project with only main package.

Whenever I try to run **`go mod init`** in a directory (that's outside my `$GOPATH`), I get this error:

`go: cannot determine module path for source directory /Users/... (outside GOPATH, no import comments)`

Is it not possible to init module without using git (or other VCS)? Or is there any workaround?

Comment: Typically if project is not under VCS (at-least locally) `go mod` won't be able to detect the module path. It better to create `go.mod` manually and mention `module modulepathhere` then save it or in your go source code mention import path comment like `package main // import "github.com/user/modulename"`. Then run `go mod init`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Is it not possible to init module without using git (or other VCS)? Or
>   is there any workaround?

Yes, it is possible to init the modules without using VSC,  initializing the module does not have to do anything with git or any other VCS.

This error occurs when the module name is not entered while `init` the module so to generate a module `modulename` write this command.

```
$ go mod init modulename
```

The content of the `go.mod` would be

```
module modulename
```

**EDIT:**

To use the modules from local repository use the `replace` directive

In your main module where you are checking your local module add the following lines

```
replace "X" v0.0.0 => "{location To your local module}"
require "X" v0.0.0
```

And then in your main project, import package *util* from module X you can simply do:

```
import "X/util"
```

Now when you will do `go build` it will look for this local module on the location you have given in the mod file of the main project.

[**For more explanation**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52124448/4544967)

Comment: Incomplete answer. How to use your own projects modules from local git repository?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52124448/4544967 To use the module locally please refer this answer. I'll update this answer too.

Comment: @VasileM I hope this completes the answer.

Comment: With this: ` replace "X/v2" v2.1.0 => "manually path"` you are pointing to any path (v1, v3, etc) distinct to v2. Where is the improvement of go mod to get your version automatically by git tag?

Comment: With this option you are doing a lot of unnecessary work. You can simply omit modules and pointing to any path manually (it's fast)

Comment: When I will be testing it locally then I should have known that which version I want to check. Tagging is enabled by default on remote repo but I am not sure for the local because the git tags are not pushed by default to the remote repo.

Comment: @VasileM An edit would be appreciated in this answer. You can suggest me a better solution for it.