# go modules installing go tools

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm using go modules as dependency management, and I'm having problem to install something like this:

```
go get -u github.com/go-critic/go-critic/...
```

the result from above was:

```
go: cannot find main module; see 'go help modules'
```

Comment: Did you init main module "go mod init <module name>"? For better understanding go to this stackoverflow question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328952/how-to-use-a-module-that-is-outside-of-gopath-in-another-module

Comment: sorry for the bad description, my problem is to install cli tools into my $GOPATH/bin directory.

Comment: See this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313319/11210494), which covers options for Go 1.11, the related functionality added in Go 1.12, and what hopefully will be supported in Go 1.14.

Comment: `go install golang.org/x/tools/...@latest`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Edit:** *The original answer herein referred specifically to the state of the tooling in Go 1.11.  Since the release of Go 1.12, this is no longer accurate.  Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57317864/11210494), and the ones it links to, for details of handling this situation in Go 1.12 and later.*

If the `GO111MODULE` var is set to `on`, you have to be inside an initialized go module directory tree in order to use `go get`, even if you're trying to get a *tool* rather than a new *dependency*.  This is a known and heavily debated issue:

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27643

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24250

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25922

The solution, short term, is to run `GO111MODULE=off go get <tool>`.  This explicitly disables the module support, even if you're in a module package currently, and forces it to only utilize your GOPATH.

Long-term, figuring out what the best solution is to support tool install via `go get` (or another command, like `go install` with a flag) is an ongoing area of discussion with 
little in the way of established consensus as of yet.  However, there's a [PR open](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/148517/) for Go 1.12 that, if accepted, will allow `go get` to simply work while outside a module, even with `GO111MODULE=on` set.

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#why-does-installing-a-tool-via-go-get-fail-with-error-cannot-find-main-module => GO111MODULE=on  or  GO111MODULE=auto

Comment: FWIW, this answer _was_ correct, but is no longer correct. See this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57317864/11210494) for more details and the answer as of Go 1.12, 1.13, and the likely new option in Go 1.14 for getting a tool without it updating your go.mod. Also, that answer covers what to do if you _want_ to explicitly track a tool as a versioned dependency in your go.mod (e.g., maybe because you want everyone to use the exact same version of a linter or code generator to avoid flapping due to slightly different versions of a tool in use by different people).

Answer (score 19):

Several of the other answers here have grown stale at this point.

There are at least two cases to consider:

#### Case 1

You want to install a tool, but you don't want to modify your current `go.mod` to track that tool as a dependency.

In short, with Go 1.12 or 1.13, the simplest solution is to `cd` to a directory without a `go.mod`, such as:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ go get github.com/some/tool@v1.0.1
```

Alternatively, [gobin](https://github.com/myitcv/gobin) is a module-aware command to install or run binaries that provides additional flexibility, including the ability to install without altering your current module's `go.mod`

See this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313319/11210494) for more details, including a solution for Go 1.11, as well as the likely new option in Go 1.14 for getting a tool without it updating your `go.mod`.

#### Case 2

On the other hand, if you want to explicitly track a tool as a versioned dependency in your `go.mod`, then see the ["How can I track tool dependencies for a module?"](https://go.dev/wiki/Modules#how-can-i-track-tool-dependencies-for-a-module) FAQ on the modules wiki.

In short, you create a `tools.go` file in a separate package, and set a `//go:build tools` build tag, such as:

```
//go:build tools
// +build tools

package tools

import (
    _ "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer"
)
```

The import statements allow the `go` command to precisely record the version information for your tools in your module's `go.mod`, while the `// +build tools` build constraint prevents your normal builds from actually importing your tools.

Comment: I've just spent the day trying to untangle all the problems caused by the `tools.go` hack. I would suggest that people do not use it. See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/33926

Comment: For case 2, if I run `go mod download` on a freshly cloned project that has a `tools.go` file, do I then have to manually run `go install <tool>` for each tool listed in the `tools.go` file or is there a single `go` command that installs all tools?

Comment: @SamHerrmann, yes, you then manually run `go install <tool>`

A walkthrough in (Go By Example repo)[https://github.com/go-modules-by-example/index/blob/master/010_tools/README.md] is a helpful example 

In the example of stringer, after setting of the tools.go file as shown above, you would run `> $ go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer`

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue and resolved it by the below command.

$ go env -w GO111MODULE=auto

Answer (score 5):

With [Go 1.12](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.12#modules) (February 2019), `GO111MODULE=on go get` will work.
(From [issue 24250](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24250))

### Modules

> When `GO111MODULE` is set to `on`, the `go` command now supports module-aware operations outside of a module directory, provided that those operations do not need to resolve import paths relative to the current directory or explicitly edit the `go.mod` file.
>   Commands such as `go get`, `go list`, and `go mod download` behave as if in a module with initially-empty requirements.
>   In this mode, `go env GOMOD` reports the system's null device (`/dev/null` or `NUL`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this command
`GO111MODULE=on go get -u github.com/go-critic/go-critic/...`

Comment: the magic doesnt work. i already export GO111MODULE=on. what i want is to install cli tools into my $GOPATH/bin directory with GO111MODULE=on. it made the go get tool behave different after turn on the GO111MODULE.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue on go1.11.2. Tried to set `GO111MODULE=on`, but this couldn't fix it.

My solution:

1. Upgrade to use go 1.12.5: https://golang.org/doc/install?download=go1.12.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz

   This can resolve `go: cannot find main module; see 'go help modules'` issue.
2. Then I got another issue `go: cannot use path@version syntax in GOPATH mode`,

   which can be resolved setting env `GO111MODULE=on`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was "almost" solved directly. At first it did not work. This was because the module was already initialized and I had run the "go get..." command before I had set GO111MODULE=on.

To get it working I removed "go.mod" reinitialized the mod by running "go mod init ..." and re run the necessary "go get ...." commands.