# Using "go get" to download binaries without adding them to go.mod

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm using Go modules in my project and in my build system (e.g. Travis CI) I'm downloading a command-line utility (written in Go) with `go get` to assist with my build process, e.g.:

```
go get github.com/mitchellh/gox
```

However, this `go get` causes the file to be added to my `go.mod` file. This is contaminating the build environment, causing it to be "dirty" (since there are changes to some files tracked in git, in this case go.mod and go.sum), and I use `git describe --always --dirty --tag` to describe my build, which shows up as "dirty".

Is there a way to "go get" a binary just to download it, without adding it to the go.mod/go.sum?

I've tried setting GOPATH to somewhere else, even then, `go get` updates the go.mod/go.sum to add this as an `// indirect` dependency.

```sh
dir="$(mktemp -d)"; \
  env GOPATH="$dir" go get github.com/mitchellh/gox && \
  mv "$dir/bin/gox" "$(go env GOPATH)"/bin/gox
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling modules when installing tools? For example, `GO111MODULE=off GO111MODULE=off go get -v golang.org/x/text`

Comment: This could work, but I’m assuming it’s not a long-term fix. Isn’t GO111MODULE will be ignored at some point in a newer go version when Go Modules are widely used?

Comment: I think that's far away in the horizon until everyone adapts modules. One other solution would be to change directories before installing tools. `go.mod` won't be in the current directory and modules will be disabled.

Comment: Just to clarify, it is not true that modules will be disabled if you change directories to somewhere without a `go.mod`. More details in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313319/11210494) below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hopefully in Go 1.14 there will be a new flag for `go get` that does exactly what you are asking. This is tracked in issue [#30515](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/30515) "cmd/go: offer a consistent global install command".

Prior to that, you have a few different options.

#### Go 1.12 and 1.13: change directory

If you are using Go 1.12 or later, the simplest solution is probably to move outside your current module to a directory without a `go.mod` prior to doing the `go get`, such as:

```
$ cd /tmp                              
$ go get github.com/foo/bar@v1.2.3
$ cd -                                # return to prior directory
```

#### Go 1.11, 1.12, 1.13+: gobin

[gobin](https://github.com/myitcv/gobin) is a module-aware command to install or run binaries that provides additional flexibility, including the ability to install without altering your current module's `go.mod`. See the `gobin` [README](https://github.com/myitcv/gobin#usage) and [FAQ](https://github.com/myitcv/gobin/wiki/FAQ) for more details.

#### Go 1.11: temporary module

If you are using Go 1.11 with modules, the first step is probably to upgrade to Go 1.12 or 1.13 given there are many improvements in modules. If you are required to use Go 1.11 and want to use the `@version` syntax without updating your current module's `go.mod`, then one approach is to create a temporary module:

```
cd $(mktemp -d) && go mod init tempmod && go get github.com/foo/bar@v1.2.3
```

This is because in Go 1.11, you can't use the `@version` syntax unless you are in a module, which was relaxed in Go 1.12. This approach has been automated by a [simple shell script](https://gist.github.com/rogpeppe/7de05eef4dd774056e9cf175d8e6a168) by [@rogpeppe](https://github.com/rogpeppe).

#### Additional Details

In general, the `go` command in module-module always determines what module it is "in", which is based on the current working directory when you invoke the `go` command.  (You could make an analogy to how `make` without any args will look for a makefile in the current working directory, or how historically `go build` without any args will build the current working directory, etc.).

With modules, `go get` looks for a `go.mod` file in the current working directory or any of its parents, and `go get` will use the constraints listed in any `go.mod` as part of solving for versions, as well as update the `go.mod` if needed based on doing the `go get`. That is why your `go.mod` file is updated if you run `go get` from within an existing module.

On the other hand, starting with Go 1.12, if you are in a directory that is not part of any module (that is, the directory does not have a `go.mod`, nor do any of its parents), then there is no `go.mod` to update, but the `go` command is still able to operate in module mode and use the `@version` syntax.

From the [Go 1.12 release notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.12#modules):

> When GO111MODULE is set to on, the go command now supports module-aware operations outside of a module directory, provided that those operations do not need to resolve import paths relative to the current directory or explicitly edit the go.mod file. Commands such as go get, go list, and go mod download behave as if in a module with initially-empty requirements. In this mode, go env GOMOD reports the system's null device (/dev/null or NUL).

Comment: The suggested edit queue is full, so I'm adding a comment instead. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/40276 tracks the proposal, which is implemented in CL https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/254365. This will most likely be included in Go 1.16, and you can run `go install github.com/foo/bar@latest` to install a command without changing go.mod.

Answer (score 27):

## Go 1.16 onwards

Go 1.16 (released February 2021) includes a change that makes it possible to install a binary without affecting `go.mod`.

[Issue 40276](https://golang.org/issue/40276) tracks the proposal:

> cmd/go: 'go install' should install executables in module mode outside a module

This was implemented in [CL 254365](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/254365). As part of this change, you can run e.g.:

```
go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports@latest
```

to install a binary without affecting `go.mod`.

To install a specific version, replace `@latest` with e.g. `@v0.1.5`.

Comment: Note, `@latest` or similar is required for this to work

Comment: Note that `@latest` will not select the latest major version, it will only select the latest minor version for the major version given in the import path. For example, if you need v2 of a tool, you need `/v2@latest`.

Comment: Note also that `go install ...@latest` does not work with modules that have `replace` directives in their `go.mod` files. For those modules you still need to download the repository (or clone it) locally, then use `go install` inside the repository without any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Per `go help build`:

> The -mod build flag provides additional control over updating and use of go.mod.
>
> If invoked with -mod=readonly, the go command is disallowed from the implicit automatic updating of go.mod

Comment: 1. Sadly `go get -mod=readonly github.com/mitchellh/gox` still updates `go.mod`. This could be a legit golang issue, however. 2. rest of the sentence you quoted goes like `...Instead, it fails when any changes to go.mod are needed.`

Comment: `go get -mod=readonly` will be fixed in 1.13 https://github.com/golang/go/issues/30667

Comment: @georgeok that issue is unrelated.