Dependency on a unpublished package for a "go:generate" instruction get removed by `go generate ./...` and `go mod tidy`
I'm facing an issue with an import required for a go:generate instruction from another module that doesn't have a published version yet. The dependency is considered indirect and is removed by go mod tidy or go generate.
I have a file with the go:generate instruction calling a script from another repo:
//go:generate go run github.com/my_module/config_gen

package config

[...]

Since the config_gen package doesn't have a published version, I fetch it by specifying the commit hash:
go get github.com/my_module/config_gen@5b7a5522

This results in the following go.mod configuration:
module github.com/my_other_module/src/api

go 1.22.4

require (
    github.com/99designs/gqlgen v0.17.35
    [...]
)

require (
    github.com/my_module/config_gen v0.0.0-20240822134450-5b7a55227345 // indirect
    github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify v1.7.0 // indirect
    [...]
)

However, since this dependency is marked as indirect, it gets removed whenever I run go mod tidy or go generate ./.... the line: github.com/my_module/config_gen v0.0.0-20240822134450-5b7a55227345 // indirect is removed from my go.mod file
I found a similar issue there where they suggest adding an import like import _ "B/cmd/tool" to force go.mod and go.sum to retain the required entries. However, this doesn't work in my case because I get the following compile error:
import "github.com/my_module/config_gen" is a program, not an importable package

Indeed, my config_gen module has a main package and a main function, so it can be run with go run ....
I'm stuck and unsure how to handle this situation. How can I ensure that my go:generate dependency is not removed by go mod tidy or go generate, given that it is an unpublished package?
PS: I have a dirty fix that work at the moment but is absolutely not satisfying. I created a "nothing" package in my github.com/my_module/config_gen module with a Nothing() function and then I add a fake dependency on this package in my github.com/my_other_module/src/api:
//go:generate go run github.com/my_module/config_gen

package config

import "github.com/my_module/config_gen/nothing"

func uglyFix() {
    nothing.Nothing()
}

Like this the dependency is not indirect anymore and it is not removed with go mod tidy

Add the dependency with a file specifically for tools https://stackoverflow.com/a/57317864/32880

Thanks! that is indeed what I was looking for

As suggested by @JimB in a comment the recommended solution is to add a tools.go file in the project (How can I track tool dependencies for a module?)
//go:build tools
// +build tools

package tools

import (
    _ "github.com/my_module/config_gen"
)

