# How to manage dependency version in git

Tags: git, versioning

There are multiple projects and they all are dependent on each other. I want to manage the versions for all.
e.g. 
There are three projects:
 1. A ---> Contains schema
 2. B ---> Contains config
 3. C ---> Contains actual api code

Now, I want to manage the version of all the dependent projects in project C. 
How to do that?

Comment: git is not designed to handle dependencies, packages are. You'd better use packaging.

Comment: It is golang project. How to do that in go?

Comment: I don't know go, but google seems to have quite a lot of hits on the subject (go dependencies and packaging)

Comment: That said, if you want a painful solution using git, you may use submodules, but it requires extra care when working on your repository.

Comment: Additional info: These are two different projects and interact via rest calls or kafka only.

Comment: if you want to ask how to do that in go, consider closing this question and opening a new one. Answer to the question as it is is "you shouldn't do this with git, but instead with some packaging mechanism/build tool"

Answer (score 0):

> It is golang project. How to do that in go?

With [Go modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules), which would record those dependencies with `go.mod`/`go.lock` files: those files would be recorded in your project C Git repo as part of C source codebase.
See an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52330233/6309).

Comment: These are two different projects and interact via rest calls or kafka only.

Comment: @SurinderRajpal So you need to define a third project, which will manage the interaction, REST API calls and Kafka calls, and will be used by the first two projects.

Comment: Let me explain it again:  
There are two two projects:  
**A** --> Which takes oracle data and puts that in kafka  
**B** ---> Which takes data from kafka and converts it to mongo.  
Now, I want to manage which version of A is compatible with which version of B.  
Suppose, A has version 2.1.1 and B version compatible for this is 3.2.1.  
Now A has version 2.4.3 and B version compatible for this is 3.4.1.

Comment: @SurinderRajpal So this is not a Go dependency issue, but a runtime data dependency compatibility one?

Comment: you can say that.