# go modules - replace does not work - replacement module without version must be directory path (rooted or starting with

Tags: go, go-modules

I just want to use a local package using go modules.

I have these files in a folder goweb:

[image]

and go.mod

module goweb

```
go 1.12

require mypack v0.0.0

replace mypack => ./src/mypack
```

But `go.mod` complains:

```
replacement module without version must be directory path (rooted or starting with .
```

go get -u ./...

```
go: parsing src/mypack/go.mod: open <local path>/goweb/src/mypack/go.mod: no such file or directory
go: error loading module requirements
```

So I am missing some path structure here

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If your app and the package it uses are part of the same go module, you don't have to add it to `go.mod`, you can just refer to it.

If they are not part of the same go module, then you can follow these steps:

The path you specify for the `replace` directive must be either an absolute path or a relative path, **relative to the module's root**.

So if `mypack` is a sibling of your module's root, you could use this:

```
replace mypack => ../mypack
```

Also, for this to work, you also have to "convert" `mypack` into a go module (`mypack` must contain a `go.mod` file). Run `go mod init mypack` in its folder.

Also check out related question: [How to use a module that is outside of "GOPATH" in another module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328952/how-to-use-a-module-that-is-outside-of-gopath-in-another-module/52330233#52330233)

Comment: Thanks, I get the same error - I updated with go get giving the same error

Comment: There is some inconsistency in the folders you gave in the question. At first you say they are inside an `src` folder, but in the error message there is no `src` folder: `/goweb/mypack/go.mod`. Please correct them.

Comment: Ok, now for this to work, `mypack` must be a go module, it must have a `go.mod` file.

Comment: See edited answer. If they are both inside the module's root, you can use it (import it) without listing it in `go.mod`. You only need to `require` and `replace` it if it's outside of the module's root.

Comment: Hmm, I think I have see example of using local packages like this. HJow do you use local packages?

Comment: Please see the linked question: [How to use a module that is outside of “GOPATH” in another module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328952/how-to-use-a-module-that-is-outside-of-gopath-in-another-module/52330233#52330233)

Comment: Wait, does that mean that the replace directives will only work if all modules depending on a single module example.com/mycorepackage I must ensure that the location of this module in the fs is relative to the dependant packages in exactly the same way? I have some packages which would require replace ../../mycorepackage and some which require only ../mycorepackage.

Seems a bit strange to me that replace does not resolve relative to the workspace file?!

Answer (score 2):

I had this scenario while updating from Go 1.12 to Go 1.19; Quite a lot has changed.

I had the Protobuffer files in a separte folder called `interfaces` out as shown below.

Inside each `microservice_x` I was creating a directory called `generated` to hold the protoc generated artefacts.

Now I need to do a `go mod init` in the `generated` folder ; along with the `replace` keywords in respective go mod files

Illustrative code here https://github.com/alexcpn/go_grpc_2022 for better understanding. Please check the Make file where the build is happening.

```
go_grpc_2022$ tree
.
├── interfaces
│   └── microservice_1
│       └── test.proto
├── LICENSE
├── microservice_1
│   ├── generated
│   │   ├── go.mod
│   │   ├── microservice_1
│   │   │   ├── test_grpc.pb.go
│   │       └── test.pb.go
│   ├── go.mod
│   ├── go.sum
│   ├── integration_test
│   │   └── validation_test.go
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── server
│   │   ├── go.mod
│   │   ├── go.sum
│   │   └── server.go
│   ├── test_client
│   │   └── client.go
│   └── test_server
│       ├── go.mod
│       ├── go.sum
│       └── main.go
└── README.md
```