# Replacing inconvenient package name. Got error: replacement module without version must be directory path (rooted or starting with ./ or ../)

Tags: go, import, package, rename

### Problem

In go.mod file I wrote:

```
module github.com/Siiir/vector

go 1.17

require github.com/huandu/go-clone v1.3.2 // indirect
replace clone => github.com/huandu/go-clone[v1.3.2]
```

It says that I cannot do such a replacement.
I actually solved my problem with the name of imported package.
It is convenient & working without that dash. I found that I can use `clone.something` to refer to a function.
No need to type `go-clone.something`.
**Anyway, assume that a package name is indeed crazy or inconvenient. How can I replace it?**

### What I've seen:

- I've seen a sibling question:
  [go modules - replace does not work - replacement module without version must be directory path (rooted or starting with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55533971/go-modules-replace-does-not-work-replacement-module-without-version-must-be)

### What I tried:

1. Working with terminal:

- go mod edit -replace=clone=github.com/huandu/go-clone
  **got:**  `go: -replace=clone=github: unversioned new path must be local directory`

2. manual editing:

- Attempts like: replace clone => github.com/huandu/go-clone[v1.3.2]
  **got:**  `replacement module without version must be directory path (rooted or starting with ./ or ../)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anyway, assume that a package name is indeed crazy or inconvenient. How can I replace it?

You cannot.

And you should not. The import path is something you write just once in the `import` declaration and the package name can be changed on a per file level with `import nicename "something.you.think/is-totally/inconvenient/and/unacceptable-to/your_taste"` .

Comment: Thank you, nickname on per file level was something I deeply forgot.