# View package documentation locally in a browser

Tags: go

I want to see locally how my package documentation will look.  That is, I want to see the same kind of thing you see on [godoc.org](https://godoc.org/strings), but locally.

I have a simple example folder locally, but I can't get it to work.  It correctly outputs text documentation:

```
~/code/go/gonotes (master) $ godoc .
PACKAGE DOCUMENTATION

package gonotes
    import "."


FUNCTIONS

func Blah()
    Here is header

    Blah is function being use to test:

    - go documentation
    - blah like things

    It is nice
```

But if I run `godoc -http=:6060`, and navigate to `http://localhost:6060/`, I see essentially the same content I'd see on the golang.com homepage.  `http://localhost:6060/gonotes` displays

```
lstat $GOROOT/gonotes: no such file or directory
```

Am I misunderstanding how the `-http` works?  Is there any way to preview the http version of my docs locally?

### UPDATE

I was able to get it to appear by copying the files into `src/gonotes` and then running:

```
GOPATH=/Users/jonah/code/go/gonotes godoc -http=:6060
```

so that the actual files were available at `/Users/jonah/code/go/gonotes/src/gonotes`.

This has the side effect of not showing any of the Third part libs installed in my default `GOPATH`, so I'd still like to find a solution that just allows me to add the current directory, as is, without adding `src/curdir` to it, and still have it show up.

Comment: `godoc -http` will serve doc of all available packages, including the standard library. Worry not, your own packages are amongst them, just look again. As a shortcut, just type `http://localhost:6060/pkg/your/package`.

Comment: @icza Thanks. I tried `http://localhost:6060/pkg/gonotes` and got `cannot find package "." in: /src/gonotes`.  Do I need to put my source files under `src`?  Currently they're just in in the folder `gonotes`, as you can see from the terminal session I included in the OP.

Comment: For that to work, your `gonotes` package would have to be inside `GOPATH/src/gonotes`.

Comment: You can't just put your Go code into arbitrary folders. You must follow the `GOPATH` convention, for details, see [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).

Comment: @icza isn’t this the whole point of using go modules?  so you aren’t bound to GOPATH?

Comment: Not the whole point, but yes, if using modules, you don't have to use `GOPATH` (you didn't mention modules before though). But then why are you setting `GOPATH`? `GOPATH` and modules are _mutually exclusive_, see [Go Modules does not recognize files under GOPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650450/go-modules-does-not-recognize-files-under-gopath/55650622#55650622). The `godoc` tool is not module-aware, and it is being deprecated, so for now if you want to see your package docs locally in `godoc`, you have to resort to putting their sources in an `src` folder.

Comment: This comment is the answer to my question.  Feel free to add as a proper answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### In `GOPATH` mode

`godoc -http` will serve doc of all available packages, including the standard library. Worry not, your own packages are amongst them, just look again. As a shortcut, just type `http://localhost:6060/pkg/your/package`.

### In module-aware mode

`GOPATH` and modules are *mutually exclusive*, see [Go Modules does not recognize files under GOPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650450/go-modules-does-not-recognize-files-under-gopath/55650622#55650622). The `godoc` tool is not module-aware, and it is being deprecated (see [deprecation warning](https://golang.org/doc/go1.12#godoc)), so for now if you want to see your package docs of modules locally in `godoc`, you have to resort to putting their sources in an `src` folder.

"Workaround" for seeing docs of module's:

- Put the repo in a folder like `/some/folder/src`
- Start godocs with `godoc -goroot=/some/folder -http=:6060`

See related issue: [support Go modules](https://github.com/golang/gddo/issues/567)

Also groups discussion: [Is the go 1.11 godoc tool 'module-aware'?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/SSv5vhCi2zs)

Answer (score 1):

In 2024, to use `godoc` in `GOPATH` mode, that is, make it serve both stdlib from `$GOROOT` and also whatever's under `$GOPATH`, you have to explicitly turn off module mode:

```
GO111MODULE=off godoc -http=:6060
```