# Go static html documentation

Tags: go, document

I'm writing Go code for a CNI company that doesn't provide Internet access to the majority of desktops and servers.  Due to the nature of the business, documentation is considered very important.  I'm looking for a method to scan my code and build static HTML pages that I can host on an internal webserver.  Ideally I'd like this to include `package main` and the functions within it.  If static content isn't an option, running a dedicated doc publishing daemon of some kind would be fine.  Are there any options?

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc (i'm not sure if `main` is supported though)

Comment: Why do you need static HTML? Why not just run `go doc` normally?

Comment: @Flimzy It doesn't have to be static. In fact, if there's a way to put the code in a repo and have `go doc` generate docs from it, that would be ideal.  Currently there seems to be a lot of overlap (and confusion) between `godoc` and `go doc`.  How do I document a `package main` using go doc?

Comment: How to document a package is a separate matter from how to consume that documentation. Which are you asking about?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it might be a solution, I'll give it a try.  I'm surprised there isn't a more off-the-shelf solution for documenting Go than having to recompile the godoc package.  Is it not a common requirement to document `package main`?

Comment: @Flimzy I want staff to consume it from a web browser.  I don't mind if it's statically generated html or dynamically generated from the source by a tool.  My only prereq's are that it can be hosted offline and includes `package main`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Now it's clear what you need (and that this is a duplicate).  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56342340/13860).

Comment: @mkriegar1 Your solution works thanks, although it only documents exported variables/methods.  I'll have a dig in the godoc source and see if there's an easy way to override that behaviour.