# How to separate code in different directory by 'go mod'?

Tags: go

My source directory layout like

```
mywork/libA
mywork/libA/liba.go
mywork/libA/go.mod
mywork/progB
mywork/progB/go.mod
mywork/progB/progb.go
```

- In mywork/libA/ directory, I type `go mod init example.com/mywork/liba`.
- In mywork/progB/ directory, I type `go mod init example.com/mywork/progb`.

libA/liba.go

```
package liba
func Hi() string {      return "hi" }
```

libA/go.mod

```
module example.com/mywork/liba

go 1.13
```

progB/progb.go

```
package main
import "example.com/mywork/liba"
func main() { println("progb:", liba.Hi()) }
```

progB/go.mod

```
module example.com/mywork/progb

go 1.13
```

The `go build` in `libA` directory is workable. But the `go build` failed in `progB` and shows

> build example.com/mywork/progb: cannot load example.com/mywork/liba: cannot find module providing package example.com/mywork/liba

How to correct it?

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-i-work-entirely-outside-of-vcs-on-my-local-filesystem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a module that is outside of “GOPATH” in another module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328952/how-to-use-a-module-that-is-outside-of-gopath-in-another-module)

Comment: I agree it is similar question, but I can not searched  the answer from error message

Answer (score 1):

progB/go.mod should add require and replace statements in https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-i-work-entirely-outside-of-vcs-on-my-local-filesystem

```
module example.com/mywork/progb

require example.com/mywork/liba v0.0.0

replace example.com/mywork/liba => ../libA

go 1.13
```