# How can I automatically add dependency packages to go.mod

Tags: go, go-modules

I have modifed an [existing github project](https://github.com/josephspurrier/gowebapp) with dozens of 3rd party imported packages but I kept the basic structure intact, which is like this:

```
.
├── config
│   ├── config.json
│   └── mysql.sql
├── gowebapp.go
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── static
├── template
│   ├── about
│   │   └── about.tmpl
│   ├── base.tmpl
└── vendor
    └── app
        ├── controller
        │   ├── about.go
        │   ├── error.go
        │   ├── index.go
        │   ├── login.go
        │   ├── notepad.go
        │   ├── register.go
        │   └── static.go
        ├── model
        │   ├── model.go
        │   ├── note.go
        │   └── user.go
        ├── route
        │   ├── middleware
        │   │   ├── acl
        │   │   │   └── acl.go
        │   │   ├── httprouterwrapper
        │   │   │   └── httprouterwrapper.go
        │   │   ├── logrequest
        │   │   │   └── logrequest.go
        │   │   └── pprofhandler
        │   │       └── pprofhandler.go
        │   └── route.go
        └── shared
            ├── database
            │   └── database.go
            ├── email
            │   └── email.go
            ├── jsonconfig
            │   └── jsonconfig.go
            ├── passhash
            │   ├── passhash.go
            │   └── passhash_test.go
            ├── recaptcha
            │   └── recaptcha.go
            ├── server
            │   └── server.go
            ├── session
            │   └── session.go
            └── view
                ├── plugin
                │   ├── noescape.go
                │   ├── prettytime.go
                │   └── taghelper.go
                └── view.go
```

Now I want to use go modules to make the project portable.

The main.go imports are like:

```
    package main

    import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "os"
    "runtime"

    "app/route"
    "app/shared/database"
    "app/shared/email"
    "app/shared/jsonconfig"
    "app/shared/recaptcha"
    "app/shared/server"
    "app/shared/session"
    "app/shared/view"
    "app/shared/view/plugin"
)
```

As you can see the code mostly sits in `vendor/app` folder.

I have added several other packages to that.

The problem is that manually adding the packages to go.mod is so tedious, and after all I may miss some imports.

So I'm wondering if there are some automatic tricks to fetch the dependencies to go.mod?

Answer (score 13):

Initialize the module with `go mod init module-path`, this will create the `go.mod` file. Build the project with `go build`. It automatically adds all dependencies to `go.mod`, transitively.

No manual step is involved. The `go` tool does everything for you. Of course you may edit the `go.mod` file and "fine-tune" the included versions if the automatically chosen ones do not fit your need / intent. See [Version Selection](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#version-selection) how it is done by default.

Note that starting with Go 1.16, `go mod tidy` might be needed to add depencencies.

Comment: Well I get this error: `build proj1: cannot load app/route: malformed module path "app/route": missing dot in first path element`

Comment: Then fix that error first. You have to use full import path, with module path prefixed. E.g. if your module has path `github.com/joe`, and your module contains `app/route` folder, you have to import that as `github.com/joe/app/route`, and not just as `app/route`.

Comment: Actually `app/route`  is located in `/home/me/go/src/proj1/vendor/app/route`. So how should I modify the import to be useful?

Comment: `vendor` is special, it is only used if you pass `-mod=vendor`, but then all your deps should be vendored. Decide what you want. If you don't want to vendor all your deps, then move `app/route` to the project root or to another module which you can import properly. To use a folder on your disk, see [How to use a module that is outside of “GOPATH” in another module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328952/how-to-use-a-module-that-is-outside-of-gopath-in-another-module/52330233#52330233)

Comment: Well, the project from github https://github.com/josephspurrier/gowebapp and modified the code heavily. As you can see most of th code is  in `vendor` but inside that there are imports from github and google. So what why do you suggest me to do to add `go.mod` with the least re-structuring?

Comment: You may try `go mod vendor` which downloads all dependencies into the `vendor` folder. But your setup seem like it asks for trouble itself. _"don't like github imports"_ is not a valid argumentation here. You're not making your life easier.

Comment: @Babr Sorry, it's `go mod vendor`. But you should not force workarounds, you should try to properly import existing dependencies.

Comment: Still get error: `module-path imports
        app/route: malformed module path "app/route": missing dot in first path element`

Comment: @Babr Yes, `go mod vendor` can only download properly imported packages.

Comment: So please tell me how to modify the imports properly. I'm just using the `gowebapp` imports which are like `import (
 "net/http"

 "app/shared/session"
 "app/shared/view"
)` see:https://github.com/josephspurrier/gowebapp/blob/master/vendor/app/controller/index.go

Comment: Modify the imports to be valid. `app/shared/view` is not a valid import path if there is no module and its package denoted by this path.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me. Can you give me an example, for example what should be the correct import instead of `"app/route"`? The project was built and runnig fine before I added `go.mod`.

Comment: The import path must point to a valid package. If there is a published repo such as `github.com/icza/bito`, that is a valid import path. The path `this.leads.to.nowhere/invalid` is not a valid import path, there is no repository hosted there. If you use the `replace` directive in `go.mod` (see linked answer in my previous comment), you may designate any path to point to an existing package in your disk, then that will also be a valid import path.

Comment: So how would you replace "app/route" in my case where I have downloaded https://github.com/josephspurrier/gowebapp and modifed the code base? Please give me an example instead of  lectures.

Comment: @Babr That depends how where you put it, and what have you modified in it. Have you thought about that you could learn more from lectures than from a direct answer without reasoning?

Comment: I have added some controllers, routes and models. I did not change the basic structure of the `gowebapp`, and I'm still in dark on how to modify the imports in order to make it modules-friendly.

Answer (score 3):

```
go mod tidy
```

Run that command is the short answer