# What should I name my Go package if I don't know where I will host it?

Tags: go

I want to write a new Go package. If I type `go mod init github.com/user/hello`, would that be a correct name, if I end up deciding to host it in another location and not github?

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can use "foo.bar/anything" or "example.org/spam" or whatever you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rename the module later, so it plays no important part. Keep using that.

To rename a module in `go.mod`, you may edit it (it's a simple text file), or you may run the command:

```
go mod edit -module github.com/newuser/newhello
```

Note that this will only rename the module in `go.mod`, but if your module consists of multiple packages which import each other, the `import` statements will not be edited, you have to manually edit those or use a tool to do that.

If you want to test your module before pushing it to a remote repository, see [How to use a module that is outside of "GOPATH" in another module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328952/how-to-use-a-module-that-is-outside-of-gopath-in-another-module/52330233#52330233)